# TwoSums code Python (Locating Indexes of Sum Values)

Tags: python

Could someone please explain the lines of the following code? I am having difficulty visualizing how the hash table/map stores the values. I am also confused as to how `return [prevMap[diff],i]` returns the values of the indexes which correspond to the sum.

## Code

```py
List=[2,4,5,6]

target=6


class Solution:

    def twosums(self, nums, target):
        
        prevMap={} # val: index 
        
        for i, n in enumerate(nums): # key and value insertion ? 
            diff=target-n # 
            
            if diff in prevMap:
                return [prevMap[diff],i]
            prevMap[n]=i

#N=Solution() 

print(Solution().twosums(List, target))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Some words about `dict`

Let's imagine that we are bosses of a big company. We want to analyze our incomes for past years. For that we need to be able to name a year to computer and receive the income for that year in response. The structure good for such a purpose is `dict` (you are calling it "map"). The incomes information can be programmed like this:

```py
incomes = {
    2010: "$100.000",
    2011: "$150.000",
    ...
    2020: "$750.000",
    2021: "$1.000.000"
}
```

If you want to know the income for year `2020`, you can simply type `incomes[2020]`.

Technically, `dict` just stores `key: value` pairs. In the example above `keys` are years and `values` are incomes.

Note, that there are some restrictions:

1. Each `key` should be unique. It's not possible map to store two pairs `key_1: value_1` and `key_2: value_2` where `key_1` is equal (it's not the most appropriate word here, but for simplicity let's say "equal") to `key_2`.
2. Each `key` should be hashable: it should provide `__hash__` method and be comparable (it should provide `__eq__` or `__cmp__` methods). Note that in-built *mutable* objects (such as `list`) *are not hashable*. Checkout [Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) for further details.

### Your case

- `prevMap` is a `dict` which will store `number from nums: it's index` pairs.
- `enumerate` returns a `generator` of `(index, value)` tuples. In your case it means that `n` is a number from `nums` and `i` is an index of `n` in nums.
- `diff` is a number which we can add to `n` to get `target`.
- The line `prevMap[i] = n` is simply adds pair `n: i` to `prevMap` (if there where a pair `n: another_i` this pair will be overwritten by `n: i`). It allows us to remember previous values of `n` and corresponding indexes.
- Expression `diff in prevMap` returns `True` iff there is a key `diff` in `prevMap`. If it is, it means that there is a number in `nums` which sums up to `target` with `n` and we can get its index by typing `prevMap[diff]`.

Comment: NIce, detailed answer. But... your example dictionary is not valid code due to those thousand separators!

Comment: Yep, it's just an illustration. I've made them strings in edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Amazing explanation thank you so much !! I'm sorry if it was a dumb question I was just having difficulties conceptually understanding it due to the dict vs list attributes. I only have one question. How would the code be modified to account for multiple instances in which the sum could be found in a given list. Ex,.. list=[1,2,3,4,5,6], target= 5.